C# reflection: Get static method with multiple generic overloads
How we can get a method such as Tuple.Create that has multiple generic overloads through reflection and use it with our custom generic type arguments?
usecase: the generic type arguments are known only at runtime.

usecase: reflection is useful only at runtime.

Use Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter to create Types representing the generic type parameters of the method. You pass it an int to indicate the index of the type parameter - the first type parameter is 0, and so on.
/ this gets the Create<T1,T2> method
var method = typeof(Tuple).GetMethod("Create", [
    Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0), // this represents T1
    Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(1) // this represents T2
])

As another example, you can also do things like:
GetMethod(
    "Foo", 
    [
        typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0))
    ]
)

to find a method with the signature Foo<T>(List<T>).

Greate.
Please add a workaround for .NET Standard 2.0.

@MansoorOmrani On .NET Framework you will just have to loop through all the methods to find the one you want.

The trick is we should use GetMember() instead of GetMethod().
We should also cast the MemberInfo to MethodInfo in order to call the found method.
Here is the answer:
// step 1. get Tuple.Create member
var createMembers = typeof(Tuple).GetMember("Create", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
// step 2. find desired overload.
//         here we find an overload that has two parameters.
var createMethodGeneric = (MethodInfo)createMembers.FirstOrDefault(m => ((MethodInfo)m).GetParameters().Length == 2);
// step 3. create a closed-generic method out of the open-generic method definition
var createMethod = createMethodGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) });

// step 4. now the createMethod can be called
// here, we pass null to the first parameter in Invoke(), since our method is static.
var myTuple = createMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { 10, "red" });

// this is equal to the following code:
// myTuple = Tuple.Create<int, string>(10, "red");


This fails if the method Create has two parameters, but is not generic. Sweeper's answer is correct.

You can also use GetMethods instead of GetMember. This isn't a good answer.
